# Single web application or Combination of Desktop and mobile app?

Tags: web-applications, architecture, mobile-application

I am looking to develop a application where the data can be accessed from both a desktop device and a mobile device. For the most part the mobile application would need access to the data but would be separate functionality then the desktop.

I like the idea of having a single application (code base) that accomplishes both but one of the requirements for the desktop application is to display text (like a presentation) on attached screens. The desire is to display up to two attached screens (Main Display + Attached screens(up to 2)). I believe I have seen Chrome accomplish this but not sure how reliable this technology is.

Keep in mind the data would be very minimal, just need access to it from both. The mobile access could easily get away with a cached version with any updates being pulled in when connected to internet.

Looking for suggestions on whether to proceed down the route of a single application, using a browser ability to present to attached screens, or develop two separate applications.

If that is not clear please let me know and I can add further details

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Chrome, you might end up depending on some [extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-screen-presentation/hdcpaafhapbbddofomepnhhdfcpikdnf), so if you encounter some bugs, it might be tricky to get past them (you need to wait for updates).

I'm not saying which option is better, but I would quantify this decision by thinking about the following aspects:

- What evolving directions I see on this project? Is this a one-time thing, or I see lots of iterations (and maybe new features) added on this new setup?
- Is there any possibility to hit the limits of a browser (thinking more about the features of the mobile app)?
- What level of effort would go into each approach? Is there a big discrepancy?

Keep in mind that you can have a single code base (in a REST API, for example), and mobile/desktop/web apps can just fetch data and display it, no business logic in there.